# What is the meaning of inclination $1$ in $x$?

Tags: kinematics, terminology, definition, geometry

> "A block of mass $m$ is kept on an inclined plane with **inclination $1$ in $x$** What is the slope of the inclined plane?"

What does the term inclination $1$ in $x$ mean?

Answer (score 1):

Slope is rise by run (loosely saying). The statement means to say $1$ unit rise in $x$ unit run. So the slop will be $1/x$ in this case.

Answer (score 0):

It means that for every x units you travel along the inclination, the height is increased by 1 unit

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/312404)

Comment: @QuIcKmAtHs How does it not answer the question?

Answer (score -3):

Inclination $1$ in $x$ means $\sin\alpha = 1/x$.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by $\sin@$?